# How to Create MSSQL Database on a Different Disk in Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-18.04, sql-server-2017

I have a machine with Ubuntu 18.04 and MSSQL Server 2017 installed. The machine has OS disk and DATA disk. I want to create new DB on the DATA disk.

When I connect to the SQL Server from a Windows PC with Management Studio, I can't see the DATA disk in directory browser (see picture).

How do I create new DB on the DATA disk?

[image]

Comment: Does the `mssql` user/group have access to the other device?

Comment: @Larnu How do I check?

Comment: you could see what user/group users the directory and see is the `mssql` user belongs to any of those groups. You could impersonate the `mssql` account and try to access the device. By default, it won't have access to anything other than what it needs to, so if you haven't explicitly changed its permissions, it won't have access.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try to create the database with T-SQL. Something like this:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE Sales
ON
( NAME = Sales_dat,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\saledat.mdf',
    SIZE = 10,
    MAXSIZE = 50,
    FILEGROWTH = 5 )
LOG ON
( NAME = Sales_log,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\salelog.ldf',
    SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) ;
GO
```

but of course specifying the path you want.

Comment: The fact the OP can't see anything in the device is likely that the service account (`mssql`) can't access it. As the account can read the `media` folder, it can see the mount path, but it can't expand the content of that directory.